# ios - Geolocation and Tracking in a gpx file 

Tags: ios, dictionary, gps, tracking, gpx

I want to implement an application for IOS.
This application should track a route in a gpx file.
Can you tell me some links or open source project?
thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531136/easy-way-to-create-gpx-file-with-tracks see MQoder answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is a bit of an old question I guess, but I found this in my recent search to do GPX and works really well. The creator has an amazing example on Git as well to see it in action: http://gpxframework.com/

For GPX files, checkout OSRM as well: http://project-osrm.org/

Answer (score 1):

check this simple apps to create GPX file easy and free on iTunes store, you can share your gpx from this application to email, dropbox or itunes share document...

check this at [itunes.apple.com/us/app/gpx-creator/id535468654?mt=8&uo=4](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gpx-creator/id535468654?mt=8&uo=4)