# Easy way to create GPX file with tracks

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, gpx

How do I easily create a GPX file that represents a track between two points, with waypoints?

Comment: see my answer at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15524981/970353 you can use it easy...

Comment: You can use Google Maps and then this tool to convert it to GPX https://mapstogpx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the python script on this site incredibly useful and dead simple to generate a gpx file containing a track with waypoints:

https://coderwall.com/p/on-ica

Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/basuke/3605355

Answer (score 1):

This [Tool](http://gpx-poi.com) is great for that! set up a location or route and download your GPX file. dont forget to remove .txt at the end of the file.

Have FUN:D